# How to add fields to json file using bash

Tags: json, bash

I am trying to this 
`curl -s http://localhost/config/info.json | jq -r  '."info"."hostnames"'`
this outputs

```
  "hybrid_hostname": "10.1.10.10",
  "portal_hostname": "",
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I want to append this output to another json file `foo.json` under `.`

foo.json after the operation should is expected to be

```
{
   "_comment": " these values already exist here"
   "hybrid_hostname": "10.1.10.10",
   "portal_hostname": "",
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: Add `>> foo.json` to the end of your command maybe?

Comment: Yes, I tried this. The problem with this method it is, it creates a new blob, I just want to add the output, under a key.

Comment: Ok, maybe click `edit` under your question and be a bit more explicit about the expected result. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
$ jq '{ "_comment": " these values already exist here" } + .' your.json
{
  "_comment": " these values already exist here"
  "hybrid_hostname": "10.1.10.10",
  "portal_hostname": "",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In one step:

```
curl -sS http://localhost/config/info.json |
  jq --argfile foo foo.json '
    $foo + .info.hostnames'
```

Notice that `."info"."hostnames"` can be abbreviated.